# Unable to read SQLite database deployed on a device

Tags: android, sqlite, readonly

I am developing an application on android, using an embedded sqlite database that I have prealably created. 
While deploying the application on my device (an HTC wildfire), I retrieve the existing database from the assets folder and read the data in the database. At this point everything is alright.
The issue I am facing is about the fact that all the opération I am doing on the database like Add, Edit or Remove doesn't work. It seems like the database is in readonly mode but the select operation is working fine and I get my list displayed.
Please, I need your advise!

See below the code I am using to create the database:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydb.sqlite";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;  
private static String DATABASE_PATH = "";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);     
    try {
        copyDataBase(context);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    DATABASE_PATH = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getAbsolutePath();
}

private void copyDataBase(Context context) throws IOException{       
    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream input = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);        
    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(DATABASE_PATH); 
    //transfer bytes from the input file to the output file
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = input.read(buffer))>0){
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    //Close the streams
    output.flush();
    output.close();
    input.close();
}   

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {       
    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DATABASE_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {      
    Log.w(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "New version : " + newVersion);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS destiny");     
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS intention");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS innerself");
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

Regards.

Comment: any errors? can you demonstrate how do you retrieve a database instance? do you use getWritableDatabase() or getReadableDatabase()?

Comment: I am using the getWritableDatabase() function.

Answer (score 0):

you need to copy the database to the /data/data/packagename folder, see

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: I finally resolved the issue. I was doin a mistake while copying the code indicated in url... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are forgetting to commit your Database Operations?
Example: http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Accessing-Data-With-Android-Cursors/3/